# bash: full path to exe required to run an exe?

Tags: xcode, bash, console

I have an Xcode executable "testexe" in the following path /Users/user1/bin/
If I try to run the executable from that current directory in Terminal App (Console) by just typing testexe from the bash prompt, I get the error "bash: testexe: command not found"

But, when I provide the full path /Users/user1/bin/testexe, it runs as expected. Even if my current directory is already /Users/user1/bin. Why?

Comment: if you're in the directory with the exe then you need to use ./testexe as your current directory isn't in your path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `/Users/user1/bin/` to your PATH variable

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/user1/bin/
```

then run textexe